# Are there Fedora drivers for Point Grey Flycapture SDK?

Tags: fedora, firefly-mv

I am using Fedora 12, and i have some problems finding drivers for my Firefly MV USB Digital camera. It seems that the drivers are only available in Ubuntu and ARM for Linux distro. Are there any source code that i can compile for the drivers so that I can operate my camera?

Answer (score 2):

did you try with *alien*?

something like

> alien -r foobar.deb

Answer (score 1):

check the official solution from the link below
http://www.ptgrey.com/support/kb/printable.asp?q=26